# IAM Policy Cognito Variables for DynamoDB LeadingKeys Restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

My setup:
- Mobile Hub
- Cognito User Pool
- Api Gateway
- DynamoDB

What I got working so far:
The User can sign up/in with the Cognito User Pool and get an Id and AccessToken.
The IdToken is used with the Api Gateway Cognito Authorizer to access the Api Gateway.
The Mapping of the user sub into the integration message to DynamoDb works.

```
"userId": {
    "S": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub"
}
```

Restricting the access to non user rows in a DynamoDb Table does not work.
The DynamoDb tables were created using Mobile Hubs Protected Table feature, which creates the following policy:

```
    "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
            "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
            ]
        }
    }
```

But thats not working, because this expression returns the Identity User Id and NOT the User Pool Sub. At first I'm not using Identity Pools and second I want to use the User Sub here.

I found out
`${cognito-idp.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<POOL-ID>:sub}` should do the trick, but thats not working too.

If I hardcode the Condition to use the Sub of my test user, everything works as expected, so the Policy itself is okay, it's only the expression to get the sub of the current user is not working correctly.

Is it possible to debug the IAM Policys to see what the values of the expressions are at runtime?

Any Ideas, hints, suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's not an easy topic...

Comment: I've also hit this problem :/

Comment: Hmm... Did you find any solution? I'm thinking about using a paid option at AWS Forums to finaly get a solution...

Comment: I haven't, so I'm just using the regular cognito-identity as my id, and I'm just hoping those IDs don't change/regenerate. I'm also saving in Dynamo the Cognito User Pool ID to a non-primary regular column... just to keep track for it for administration needs.

Comment: Hmm okay, it's too bad AWS Team does not give any answers. There are some other users having the same problem for years now: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230067

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this out by using [aws:PrincipalTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principaltag)

Pre-req is making sure that the IAM role that the Cognito User assumes has `sts:TagSession` assume role policy permission. [This allows principal tags to be passed after successful login to Cognito.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_session-tags.html)

On the Cognito Identity Pool, open Authentication Providers and find the Cognito provider. Make sure that Attributes for access control uses the default mappings which maps `username` to `sub`, or you have a custom rule set that passes the `sub` property to a PrincipalTag.

Finally you can use the tag passed in the filter of the role to only allow access to resources by that sub.

```
{
  "Action": [
    "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
    "dynamodb:Query",
    "dynamodb:PutItem",
    "dynamodb:GetItem"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
      "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "${aws:PrincipalTag/username}"
    }
  },
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/MyTableName",
  "Sid": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer now from an AWS Dev. You are only able to use the

```
${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XXXXXXX:sub}
```

variable if you configure the Cognito User Pool as an open ID Connect provider directly against IAM.

But there is a big problem, because you need to update the SSL Thumbprint of the service endpoint if the certificate changes in the Open ID Connector configuration. But you are not able to tell when the aws certificate has changed.